# Can a DXF File contain raster images (TIFF/JPG)?

Tags: image, dxf

I am maintaining a large Program with a graphical editor. Our Program can export DXF and it can  show Background Raster Images of various types (TIFF, JPG, BMP etc.).

Is it possible to embed these Raster Images in the DXF export so that they will be displayed when such a file is opened with AutoCad?

Comment: They can with 'insert' rather than 'attach' http://www.cadtutor.net/tutorials/autocad/all-about-images.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DXF supports embedded raster images. It saves them as BMP-type bitmaps, so no compression, *mucho* space bloat. They use type 310 tags, followed by the hex value of the raw image. I haven't figured out all the details.

To see how it's done, create an AutoCAD drawing with an embedded image, as described in one of these sites:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Saving-raster-image-in-DWG-file-to-eliminate-need-for-external-image-file.html

http://autocadtips1.com/2013/02/22/embed-a-picture-not-as-a-reference/

Save the drawing as a DXF, then figure out empirically what tags to include.